# Minify a JavaScript file to the root JS file extension in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Developing .NET web projects, I'm used to using either the bundleconfig.json and/or compilerconfig.json file to bundle and/or minify javascript (and css) files. Is there a way to use either of these methods or some other method to minify a source javascript file (located in a folder outside of wwwroot) to the root .js file extension? I don't want the minified output to be filename.min.js, I want it to be filename.js (but minified).

I know ultimately, I can manually rename the files to accomplish this, but I'd rather it be automated in Visual Studio if possible.

Also, if it helps, I'm currently building this project in .NET 6.

Answer (score 1):

Search for Visual Studio Code Minify plugin on Google. There are many here. For example, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BundlerMinifier  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fbdegroot.Minifier.